# Sending data to IoT device from user input

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot

I would like to send the data entered in a textbox to the IoT device instead of sending "on" which is already predefined. How can I do this?

```
<form action="/light/on" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Turn me on">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the form to be like this:

```
    <form action="/light/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="command" value="{{request.form.command}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit command">
    </form>
```

Then handle the POST request at server side accordingly.